# Delphi out of memory error when dowload file

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to download a file of 500 mb more when it's in this size gives out of memory error. I tried switching to 64 bit application and it worked. But I would need it to work in 32 bit application to download file.

```
var
  Stream: TStream;
  fileStream: TFileStream;
  Buffer: PByte;
  BytesRead, BufSize: Integer;
  Size: int64;
begin
  BufSize := 1024;
  fileStream:= TFileStream.Create(GetCurrentDir()+'\DownloadFile.zip', 
                                  fmCreate);
  GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);

  Stream := getDownload(size);

  if (Size <> 0) then
  begin
    repeat
       BytesRead := Stream.Read(Pointer(Buffer)^, BufSize);

       if (BytesRead > 0) then
       begin
          fileStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(Buffer)^, BytesRead);
       end;
       Application.ProcessMessages
    until (BytesRead < BufSize);

    if (Size <> fileStream.Size) then
    begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;

  finally
     FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
     fileStream.Destroy;
  end;
end;   

function TServiceMethods.getDownload(out Size: Int64): TStream;
begin
  Result := TFileStream.Create(GetCurrentDir+'\DownloadFile.zip', fmOpenRead 
  or fmShareDenyNone);
  Size := Result.Size;
  Result.Position := 0;
end;
```

Comment: What does getDownload create? Does it also create a memory stream?

Comment: I removed the XE tag. XE2 introduced the 64 bit compiler, XE was 32 bit only.

Comment: GetDownload it returns a Stream of DataSnap Server

Comment: I've switched MemoryStream to FileStream, but it keeps leaking memory.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a memory stream here. That forces the entire file into a contiguous block of memory, which as you discovered exhausts memory in a 32 bit process.

Instead, write the downloaded data directly to file. You can remove the intermediate memory stream and write directly to a file stream.

Of course, all of this assumes that `getDownload` returns a stream that performs the download as you read it. If `getDownload` reads the entire file into a memory stream then it suffers from the exact same problem as the code in this question.

Comment: How do I write directly to the file. Just return it returns me a stream from a server?

Comment: Instead of creating a memory stream and writing to it, create a file stream and write to it.

Comment: Surely David isn't the only person in the world who knows what a file stream is... Surely Google knows...

Comment: Obrigado! Vou tentar fazer.

Comment: Faça ou não faça. Não há tentar ;-)

Comment: I've changed by FileStrem but the message "out of Memory" still appears. But when I compile to 64 bits it works. Only with 32 bits does this message "out of memory" continue to appear. I do not know if I'm reading the right stream. I used the same code approach from above just changed to FileStream.

Comment: Then the problem is in the code that isn't shown here. Presumably that code downloads the entire file to memory.

Comment: This getDownload it returns a Stream from a DataSnap server. I noticed that fileStream is also copying to memory until it pops up.